# Photoshop replace color with specific color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, design-principles

What is the best way to replace color with a specific color?

I tried (Image > Adustments > Replace Color > Select Color with color dropper+ > Select Hex / rgb replacement color.

I would like the final result to look solid like the cad below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think its clear what you're asking. Consider an [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the result you're looking for would be this?

[image]

It was pretty simple using Photoshop actually.  At first I attempted using the color replacement tool. After five minutes experimenting with that tool, I decided good old fashion masking would be the easiest way to go.

1. Using my polygon lasso tool, I selected the outside beige color border then I hit command + j which copied that selection to a new layer.
2. Then at the bottom of the layers palette, I clicked the icon to create a new fill or adjustment layer and added a new hue/saturation layer and I just adjusted the sliders until I got the desired color. I also use the option to have this color mask only be applied to this one border layer only

[image]

3. Then going back to my original image, I went to menu item Select/Color Range to select the grays in the image.  I used my + eyedropper tool to try to achieve grabbing all of the grays that I could.

[image]

4. I repeated the process. I hit command + j which copied that selection to a new layer. At the bottom of the layers palette, I clicked the icon to create a new fill or adjustment layer and added a new hue/saturation layer and I just adjusted the sliders until I got the desired color. I also use the option to have this color mask only be applied to this layer only.

[image]

5. Holding the command key, I clicked on that new layer. This automatically creates a selection of that layer.  Then I went to menu item Select/Inverse and selected my original image again.  I hit command + j which copied that selection to a new layer. At the bottom of the layers palette, I clicked the icon to create a new fill or adjustment layer and added a new hue/saturation layer and I just adjusted the sliders until I got the desired color. I also use the option to have this color mask only be applied to this layer only.

[image]

Comment: @Socks No need to thank me. Upvoting my answer would be good enough ;-)

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to create a mask for each color you want

Using your Magic wand tool, configure the tolerance and pick a sample size of more than a point sample, and youll get a selection to nearly where you want it.

[image: the marching ants]

Create a new solid color, and photoshop should create the mask along with it based on your selection. Change the feathering on your mask in order to blur it to match the pattern.

Create another solid color underneath it, this one will be unmasked, and your base color.

[image: Mask Properties]

In GIMP I know there is a single button for this operation, but in photoshop its a bit more complex.

Answer (score -1):

That rug is basically 1-color + grayscale, so that helps simplify the process.

- Cut out the rug, move it to a new layer and set the blending mode to Multiply.
- Ctrl + click the rug layer to select the rug.
- On a transparent background layer, fill that selection with your tan color.
- Back up to the rug layer, adjust the Hue/Sat. Change the "Master" selection to just "Red" and start adjusting the hue/sat of the pink
  area.
- Finally, adjust your Levels or Curves as you please and feel free to adjust the Hue/Sat on the background layer.

Comment: I am interested in seeing some screenshots of your results