# Swap the two colours around in an image in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

Please could someone advise the best way, step by step, to swap the green with the white in this image?

[image: Swap two colours around in an image]

I've got as far as managing to make all of the white a selection in it's own layer.

I have tried various fiddling about with inverting colours, replacing colours etc and not managed to achieve what I'm after.

If it isn't obvious, it is a basic globe and I'm basically wanting to make all the land white and all the sea transparent (will appear green because of the background layer though).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photoshop replace color with specific color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80612/photoshop-replace-color-with-specific-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case the absolutely easiest thing to do is to use a Gradient Map and remap greens to whites and whites to greens:

[image]

**update:**

Super quick transparency.

- desaturate, levels so that image would be black-n-white
  [image]
- in the `Channels` panel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Click</kbd> to load a channel as selection. White will be fully selected, black — non-selecte
  [image]
- create `Solid Color` from selection: and done. 5 seconds, a very sharp result
  [image]
- optionally invert selection before creating a solid or invert mask colors of the solid layer to invert the transparency
  [image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have done the job well.

Comment: That will give you a two-colour result. You asked for one colour & transparency.

Comment: @zigojacko added quick method of getting transparency

Answer (score 2):

The linked question has a good explanation for a more complex process, but when there is such a simple 2-colour image, the swap is easier.

After opening the image, click the padlock in the layers list - this will make any erased background transparent rather than the background colour.

Select the Magic Wand, these were the settings I used; it's going to be reasonably tolerant on a simple image
[image]
Click anywhere in the green.
Cut.
Paste.
You now have two layers one with each colour, the green layer is selected.

Select the Paint Bucket.
Opt-click any white area.
Click in the green area.

You can now actually just switch off (or delete) the other layer & there's your image, white on transparent.

If you wanted to swap both colours, then after you opt/click white, hit X then opt-click green. This will preload both your brush colours.
You can then repeat the same process on the other layer.